# Second external display connected to M1 MacBook Pro occasionally dimming

Tags: display, thunderbolt, screen

Currently using an M1 MBP 16" but this issue happened with my older 2016 MBP 15".  Current MacOS is Ventura 13.5.2.  Using MBP with lid open, connected to two LG UltraFine 5k displays via Thunderbolt ports on left side.

The issue is that the second external display will not maintain brightness.  At least once per day it will dim to about 60% on its own, noticably dimmer than display #1, but the brightness slider in Settings->Displays shows 100% for both displays.  If I move the slider slightly left it will suddenly change to 100% brightness to match display #1, but sometime after a few hours it will revert back to the lower brightness, again while the slider still shows 100%.

The only controls available for the LG displays in Settings->Displays are the brightness slider, color profile, and rotation.  On the settings for the internal display, automatically adjust brightness is turned off, True Tone is on, Night Shift is off, and the brightness is about 60%.  The LG displays essentially have no controls of their own and I can't find a way to check if their firmware is up to date.